# Calculating normals of .3ds model

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, geometry, 3ds

I'm trying to implement .3ds importer according to [this documentation](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake2/qutils3/common/l3dslib.c) and I've approached the stage when I need to calculate vertex normals because .3ds files do not provide such. Here is the Java code:

```
/* Sctructure of vertex array is {x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1...}
*  
*  Basically, MathUtils.generateNormal_f(x0,y0,z0, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2) is cross
*  product between (x1-x0, y1-y0, z1-z0) and (x2-x0, y2-y0, z2-z0) */

normals = new float[this.vertex.length]; //every vertex has it's own normal
int n = 0;
for (int i=0; i<this.index.length; i++){
    float[] Normal = MathUtils.generateNormal_f( //getting xyz coords of 1 normal
            vertex[index[i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2], 
            vertex[index[++i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2], 
            vertex[index[++i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2]);

    normals[n++] = Normal[0];
    normals[n++] = Normal[1];
    normals[n++] = Normal[2];
}
```

Method `MathUtils.generateNormal_f(...)` tested and works fine. Result of this code can be seen below (first image). Just for example, in the second image, every normal of the model is the same and pointing towards the source of light.

**Question is:** how to calculate normals properly?

[image: Generated normals]
[image: Every vertex has (1,0,0) normal]

Answer (score 1):

Your normals might be inverted.

I do not remember the 3ds format very well, but check if you can export and import the normals from the file instead of calculating them.

P.S. also do not use magic like this:

```
vertex[index[i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2], 
vertex[index[++i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2], 
vertex[index[++i]*3], vertex[index[i]*3+1], vertex[index[i]*3+2]
```

You will get different results based on the sequence of argument evaluation. better explicitly use [i], [i+1], [i+2] when calling calculate normal...

Comment: 3ds really does not have normals, the entire application was built around the idea that normals are calculated by smoothing groups. Which works fine i you dot give the users any other options.

Comment: 1. No, normals are not inverted. They just randomly pointing everywhere. 2. 3ds format do not support normals at all. 3. Can't understand what wizards and mages you are talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

This information is correct as far as I know, and it's worked for me. For any 3 points A, B, and C on a plane, the normal, if we start at A, then B, and finally C, will be:

[image]

Where (B - A) and (C - B) each subtract two vectors, and the X sign represents finding the cross product of two vectors. The order of the points is quite important and determines our normal direction. If A, B, and C are organized in a counter-clockwise direction, than their normal will face outside the solid. If you want to know what a cross product is, then for any point P and Q, their cross product would be:

[image]

Another thing that is often done to the normal vector is that it is normalized. What this does is make the magnitude of the normal vector equal to 1 so that it is easier to work with. here's the equation:

[image]

Where the dot represents a dot product. If you don't know what a dot product is, allow me to illustrate by the following. For any points P and Q, their dot product, which is a scalar value, is:

[image]

Now that you have the surface normals, you can properly calculate the vertex normals for each vertex by averaging out the normals of any surface which shares that vertex. I don't have that formula on me, but I do know there are two approaches to find the vertex normal: weighted and non-weighted. A weighted approach involves calculating the area of each surface, while a non-weighted approach does not.

Hopefully, this information will help you. I leave the rest up to you or anyone else, as the remaining information is beyond my realm. Perhaps I'll come back and research some more on this question.